# Rotate screen to landscape in Firefox Android. Not supported anymore, but YouTube still does it. How?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I'm testing my code in Firefox for Android v110.1.0. I'm trying to rotate the page to landscape after waiting for it to be fullscreen. This used to be possible. However, apparently the ScreenOrientation.lock API is no longer supported since v97 ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock)), so this is probably not possible anymore.

Yet, somehow YouTube is still able to rotate my screen to landscape when I click the fullscreen button.

Is landscape still possible to do in some other way? Or is it special treatment of YouTube by Firefox Android?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm stuck in the same place

Comment: No, unfortunately I still don't have an answer myself